# Use of \midrule in booktabs table

Tags: tables, best-practices, rules, booktabs

Are there any formal guidelines/suggestions on the use of `\midrule` inside a `booktabs` table with just rows of identically formatted data? The [booktabs manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) is very specific about vertical rules, stating that you should

> [n]ever, ever use vertical rules.

But what about horizontal rules between data items of the same type?

This question occurred when deciding if a LaTeX table generator should insert [`\midrule`s between each line](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/666). The picture below (shamelessly stolen from there) shows the difference for the same data (but with slightly different formatting of the figures):

[image: Different ways to format the same data]

Comment: I use to say that each rule in a table is like a wall that blocks reading the table when encountered. The wall between column headers and entries is good; a block between the Datsun and the Hornet 4 lines would require motivation. There's no need to have a rule between each pair of rows: the eye can follow a row (unless the table has been artificially widened to cover the line width, which is another no-no).

Comment: @egreg I'd argue that you can see the rule as either a wall, or a guide. It makes sure your sight won't fall off a row/column while your eyes are moving horizontally/vertically (vertical is easier in general). If the table has more rows than the examples above, I can challenge you to, for example, find out the value of the column `qsec` of the 12th car in the data. I think you will have to be careful when reading that row without horizontal rules guiding your eyes. I agree these rules are more of a clutter when the table is small, though.

Comment: @Yihui That's more easily obtained by slightly increasing the leading.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `\midrule` instruction generates a horizontal line that's (i) a bit thinner than either `\toprule` or `\bottomrule` and (ii) provides some extra vertical spacing both above and below the rule. As such, a `\midrule` is best used to separate a table's header row(s) from the body of the table, and a table's body from the footer material (if present, of course).

If the table contains rows and rows of identically formatted data but no header or footer components, I would *not* use a `\midrule` at all. Inserting a `\midrule` between each and every row constitutes, to me at least, a violation of the spirit of the `booktabs` package that's nearly as egregious as using vertical rules. :-)

If it's absolutely necessary to provide some separation between the rows, I'd either adjust the amount of default vertical space or add a bit of extra vertical space -- via an instruction such as `\\[0.5ex]` -- after every fifth row or so. The amount of extra space will depend on the table's width: the wider the table, the more whitespace should be inserted after a group of rows.

---

*Addendum*: Here's a comparison of the look of the table you've linked to in your posting, first with all midrules present, and second with a midrule used only to separate the header material from the table's body. (I've also applied a few additional tweaks, such as inserting a touch of extra vertical space after the third row). I believe most readers will find the second table to be more readable -- and certainly much less cluttered -- than is the first.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\emph{Before: Lots of midrules}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrrr}
\toprule
  & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear & carb\\
\midrule
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.620 & 16.46 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4\\
\midrule
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.875 & 17.02 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4\\
\midrule
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108 &  93 & 3.85 & 2.320 & 18.61 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1\\
\midrule
Hornet 4 Drive & 21.4 & 6 & 258 & 110 & 3.08 & 3.215 & 19.44 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
\midrule
Hornet Sportabout & 18.7 & 8 & 360 & 175 & 3.15 & 3.440 & 17.02 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
\midrule
Valiant & 18.1 & 6 & 225 & 105 & 2.76 & 3.460 & 20.22 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\emph{After: Only one midrule, and some additional tweaks}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l *{7}{r} *{4}{c} @{} } 
\toprule
  & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear & carb\\
\midrule
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.620 & 16.46 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4\\
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.875 & 17.02 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4\\
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108 &  93 & 3.85 & 2.320 & 18.61 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1\\[0.6ex]
Hornet 4 Drive & 21.4 & 6 & 258 & 110 & 3.08 & 3.215 & 19.44 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
Hornet Sportabout & 18.7 & 8 & 360 & 175 & 3.15 & 3.440 & 17.02 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
Valiant & 18.1 & 6 & 225 & 105 & 2.76 & 3.460 & 20.22 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addlinespace` might be a bit more visual to the coder than `\\[...]` which often gets lost.

Comment: @daleif - To my taste, the default amount of vertical whitespace inserted by `\addlinespace` (the parameter `\defaultaddspace`, default value `0.5em`) is a bit too generous. Hence, I'd have to type something like `\addlinespace[0.6ex]` to get the space I feel right. :-)

Comment: I kind of like the larger size. In your image the extra space is hardly noticable.

Comment: @daleif - De gustibus non est disputandum, right? I happen to like typographic settings that are only barely noticeable; others, of course, have different preferences...